# Is there any relevance to Thor getting his hair cut other than comedic value?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

Is there any relevance to Thor getting his hair cut other than comedic value? It was a funny scene and leads to a small joke in *Avengers: Infinity War* but since there is no 'Samson' like effect is there some symbolism or comic reference I'm missing?

Comment: It's a crucial step in breaking him down. He loses his father, his hammer, his freedom, and then his hair. By the end of the movie, he will also lose his eye, his sister, and his home.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I get your point but he doesn't draw power from his hair and throughout the film becomes stronger and learns how to use the Lightning, also he seems more effected by the death of Heimdall than Odin etc

Comment: Hair has symbology way beyond reason for many, many people.  Just ask some dudes to shave the neck beard they've been cultivating for years.  I was once with a group of friends when a fictional character had her waist-length hair abruptly chopped to shoulder length.  Two of the women in our group reacted with more horror than if the character had suddenly lost both arms.  So, Paul D Waite's "breaking him down" theory has substance.

Comment: Out of universe it was a nice way to just give up on trying to make Chris Hemsworth blonde.

Comment: i feel like i heard somewhere that while it does add to the affect of him losing things out of his control, that he had a strand of lokis hair braided in. in some angles you can see on the left side of his head theres a braid with what looks like darker hair.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Although the haircut scene doesn't affect the movie's plot and is played for laughs, it also works as part of the movie's symbolism.

Over the course of *Ragnarok*, Thor is stripped of almost all the accoutrements we associate with Thor. He loses his father, his hammer, many of his friends, half of his cape, his freedom, and then his hair*.

By the end of the movie, he has also lost his eye, his sister, and his home. He learns that this doesn't matter — as Odin almost says, he is not the God of Hair. All that matters is him, and the people he serves and protects. Once he's learned that, he's finally ready to become King of Asgard, as he does at the end of the movie.

Miek's alive, the credits roll, and everyone lives happily ever after, yes, yes they do, no, shut up, they go to earth, *[everything works out fine](https://www.thewrap.com/thor-ragnarok-post-mid-credits-scene-explained-avengers-infinity-war/)*. [Mostly.](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2019/apr/30/avengers-endgame-cinema-fat-shaming)

---

<sub>* While his hair is perhaps not the most significant Thor-ish thing about him, it is noticed. As you mentioned, in *Infinity War* Thor arrives on earth with an enormous battle-axe, a gun-toting racoon, a sentient tree, and a robotic eye, but Steve Rogers seems to notice his haircut first.</sub>

Comment: I think it also makes him look older, more seasoned, and mature, which is appropriate, given his journey.

Comment: +1, and a shout out to the common trope [Important Haircut](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImportantHaircut)

Comment: Exactly. Symbolically, this is one of the last moments -- among several -- where Thor has **pride** stripped away, in this case represented by his hair, in order to learn **humility**.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn but didn't he 'learn humility' in the first film in order to be able to lift Mjolnir?

Comment: @Seamusthedog Two different levels of humility. The first was to not be prideful that he's better than or worthy of ordering others around. The second was to become truly humble, a servant of his people. After the first stage he's definitely more humble, to the point he can be a team player. After the second he's truly humble, to the point he can be a true **leader**.

Comment: Are you deaf? In *Infinity War*, the movie's script clearly had Thor arrive on earth with an enormous battle-axe, a sentient tree, and a gun-toting rabbit.

Comment: He doesn't, however, arrive sans an eye in Infinity War.  By that point he already has an artificial eye to replace it courtesy of the trash-rabbit.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: excellent point! I had entirely forgotten that.

Answer (score 92):

Apparently it was just because Chris didn't like wearing the wig anymore and it just took too long to get right as Eric Pearson has said in the below interview:

> "When I arrived, there were certain things they had already decided," Pearson told CBR. "'We’re going to break the hammer.. Another one was, 'We’re going to cut the hair.' I said, 'Why?' 'Hemsworth doesn’t want to wear the wig. It takes a lot of time to get it right.'"
>
> <sub>[CBR, Why Thor: Ragnarok Gave Marvel's God of Thunder A Haircut](https://www.cbr.com/thor-ragnarok-haircut-explained/)</sub>

Comment: thanks. Thought it was something like that. So nothing to do with the story then?

Comment: @Seamusthedog Doesn't appear like it but there may be something I am unaware of.

Comment: It probably makes the CGI a bit easier too.

Comment: Be that as it may, they might've tied it into the story, more significantly. (no evidence of that as yet, but it's possible).