# Why was Quicksilver worried about giving whiplash neck injuries to mutants in X-Men: Days of the Future Past, but wasn't in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, quicksilver

In *X-Men: Days of the Future Past*, when rescuing Magneto, QuickSilver held his neck and told him to be careful with the Whiplash, neck injuries due to high acceleration. But in *X-Men: Apocalypse*, he rescued a bunch of mutants from an explosion, without holding anyone's neck. Is there any explanation for this? Was he supposedly going slower when he rescued them from the explosion, is just a continuity mistake or what?

Comment: I don't have any official explanation, but my headcanon is that he's more experienced by the time of *X-Men: Apocalypse*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted in your question, in *Apocalypse*, he's trying to rescue many mutants (not just one) from an explosion (which moves much quicker than human prison guards).

As such, he doesn't have as much time to be cautious about potential non-fatal injuries caused by his speed, and isn't as concerned about them given that the immediate alternative is death or very serious injury.

Sorry! No continuity mistake for you today!

Comment: Even though he spent time messing around a little bit

Comment: @Pablo: it's essential to maintain morale during super heroics; this is why Spider-Man quips a lot and various heroes often do cool-looking poses when they land from jumps and stuff.

Comment: But does any of them check their haircut during super heroic moments though?

Comment: @Clockwork Thor and Steve have [a haircut conversation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/206600/440) right in the middle of the Battle of Wakanda!